# How can I write a query where I can get different name values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an table similar to the one below.

| ID | Name | Surname | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | K | 10 |
| 2 | B | L | 20 |
| 3 | C | M | 30 |
| 4 | A | N | 40 |
| 5 | C | O | 50 |

How can I write a query where I can get different name values? For example, the output I want to achieve is as follows:

| ID | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | C | 2 |

Comment: `MIN` and `COUNT`?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very new about MS-SQL. I don't know how to use your commands.

Comment: If you're new to SQL Server why are you using 2008? That went out of support over 3 years ago.

Comment: Aggregation is also a fundamental in SQL; if you aren't familiar with it, then it's time to learn them as they are one of the basics: [Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNT` aggregation while grouping by `Name` column along with generating ordinal numbers through use of `ROW_NUMBER()` window function such as

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS ID,
       Name, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM t
 GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cound the name by grouping the search results by Name after counting it.

Try the following:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM SOURCE_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Name
```